# Draggable popup in GWT？

Tags: gwt

When I use DialogBox to implement Dragable PopupPanel I encounter a problem that when the DialogBox pop up cause The text on the bottom page cannot be copied. How to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default [`DialogBox`](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/DialogBox.html) is **modal**, which means that:

> keyboard and mouse events for widgets not contained by the dialog should be ignored

and thus you can not select nor copy text outside dialog box.

You can change it by calling `dialogBox.setModal(false);` or by passing `modal` value to one of the following constructors:

```
DialogBox(boolean autoHide, boolean modal)
DialogBox(boolean autoHide, boolean modal, DialogBox.Caption captionWidget)
```

Comment: That's  is a very effective method.Thanks!